# Custom CKEditor build in Angular app doesn't show toolbar

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I'm trying to implement a custom build of CKEditor into my Angular app, but the toolbar just shows up empty like this:

[image]

Other than that, it works just fine, e.g. I can hit CMD+B and the selected text goes bold.

I have imported the module, defined the editor as follows in my component

```
import * as Editor from '../../../../assets/ckeditor/build/ckeditor.js';

export class MyComponent {
  Editor = Editor
}
```

and added it to my template as follows:

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" formControlName="description"></ckeditor>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I had to explicitly pass in the config that I could copy from the sample/index.html file:

```
import * as Editor from '../../../../assets/ckeditor/build/ckeditor.js';
// ...

export class MyComponent {
    // ...
    Editor = Editor;
    config = {

        toolbar: {
            items: [
                'heading',
                '|',
                'bold',
                'italic',
                'link',
                'bulletedList',
                'numberedList',
                '|',
                'indent',
                'outdent',
                '|',
                'blockQuote',
                'insertTable',
                'undo',
                'redo'
            ]
        },
        language: 'en',
        table: {
            contentToolbar: [
                'tableColumn',
                'tableRow',
                'mergeTableCells'
            ]
        },
        licenseKey: '',

    }
// ...
}
```

and in the template:

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [config]="config" formControlName="message"></ckeditor>
```

This is a step that wasn't necessary for the official build, only for the custom one.